# String with many words

Tags: bluej

I have a hangman type project. I have the J option pane window show up asking if the user wants to use their own word or a random word. If they chose random, I want to have a string with a ton of different words in it and have Java randomly select one of the words.

How would I do this? I'm writing in blue J.

Answer (score 0):

If instead of one long string you have an array of strings, where each element is a single word, then you just have to randomly choose an index.

If you HAVE to start with all the words in 1 string, then I'd use it to MAKE the array described above, doing something like this: [How to split a string in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3481828/how-to-split-a-string-in-java)